# WebView not loading local files referenced in HTML file

Tags: c#, maui

I've created a hybrid web view implementation using this [this example](https://github.com/nmoschkin/MAUIWebViewExample) in order to enable 2 way communication between my .NET Maui app and the JavaScript app that will run within the web view.

I have an index.html page sitting in the `Resources/Raw/InteractiveMap` folder that needs to load additional JavaScript files. The index.html looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Map</title>  
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app" style="width: 100%;height:100%">
        <div style="width: 100%;height:100%">
            <div id="mapTarget"></div>
        </div>
    </div>  
    <script src="./map/map.js"></script>
    <script>
        let target = document.getElementById("mapTarget");
        let map = new OdysseyMap(target);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm loading the above html file within the app like so:

```
var htmlFile = FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync("InteractiveMap/index.html").Result;
using var reader = new StreamReader(htmlFile);

var contents = reader.ReadToEnd();

MapView.Source = new HtmlWebViewSource()
{
    Html = contents
};
```

If I open the HTML file in the browser on my local machine it runs perfectly fine. However, once I deploy this to an android emulator and the web view loads it I get the following error in the console (after hooking up the Chrome remote debugger):

`Uncaught ReferenceError: OdysseyMap is not defined at about:blank:47:19`

FYI, OdysseyMap is a class defined in the script file at `./map/map.js`:

```
class OdysseyMap {
   ...
}
```

If I try to include any other js files, the global variables that they define are also not available. It seems as if the web view isn't loading the local script files (but there are no other errors in the console so I can't confirm this).

Do I need to do anything to allow the web view to be able to access those files?

Comment: You need to understand what is client code and what is server code and where the code runs.  When you open a webpage the browser is on your local machine and put in a URL where the HTML webpage is downloaded from the server into your browser.  Some of the code is run from the client and some from the server.  the code "./map/map.js" uses a period to indicate the path is the URL plus the rest of the path.   So the map.js should be on the server machine and not on client.  When you deployed your webpage to the server you did not install the java script.

Comment: This isn't running on a server, it's all local code running on the device. The files are not to be loaded from a server, but from the local filesystem.

Comment: You have a connection where one end is the client and the other end is a server.  The server is referencing the root of the URL and a path to locate the file.  So there you have a relative reference to the URL path and the file must be found by the relative path.

Comment: @Walter first time I see someone referencing to java scripts as "loading files".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so turns out you need to set the base path for the WebView to know where to load the JavaScript files from. You can do that when setting the source for the WebView:

```
var htmlFile = FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync("InteractiveMap/index.html").Result;
using var reader = new StreamReader(htmlFile);

var contents = reader.ReadToEnd();

MapView.Source = new HtmlWebViewSource()
{
    Html = contents,
    BaseUrl = "file:///android_asset/InteractiveMap/" //set this to the folder the HTML file is loaded from
};
```

After setting this it loaded the files correctly.

Comment: Hello Walter, I am in same issue with my MAUI code, as its not loading images from img folder. what path i should use for BaseUrl? my MAUI folder looks like this RAW\Html\index.html and images are in RAW\Html\img\test.png